# Formula for like in excel (Extract a string with two numbers followed by the letter M)

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a formula to look for a

> "LIKE" type logic

in excel.

For example for this string "MOBILE RPL 24M $0-39 P", I would like to extract the number "24". This number is always followed with the letter "M", but should be able to handle the multiple variations for the string shown below:

1. "MOBILE RPL 24M $0-39 P"
2. "MOBILE RPL 24 M $0-39 P"
3. "MOBILE RPL 24MO $0-39 P"
4. "MOBILE RPL 24 MO $0-39 P"
5. "MOBILE RPL 24MON $0-39 P"
6. "MOBILE RPL 24 MO $0-39 P"
7. "TV 52 RPL 24 MO $1000-4999 P"
8. "TV 52 RPL 24MO $1000-4999 P"
9. "TV 52 RPL 24M $1000-4999 P"
10. "TV 52 RPL 24 M $1000-4999 P"
11. "TV 52 RPL 24MON $1000-4999 P"
12. "TV 52 RPL 24 MON $1000-4999 P"

Comment: "I am trying to write a formula ..." What are your attempts?

Comment: none that are full proof... using the logic to find numbers within a string and check if they are divisible by 12... strings with 52 fail. also sometimes I will see 13M in other strings which will also fail

Comment: A spreadsheet formula is doubtless possible, but something like this is more easily done in VBA (largely because VBA *has* a `Like` operator already). Are you trying for a formula or a VBA function?

Comment: I don't think that's really going to help you much with what you're doing, however.

Comment: trying to stay out of VBA for this one

Comment: usually they are divisible by 12, sometimes 13, but mostly 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 108, 120

Answer (score 0):

This works on all your test cases:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,(SEARCH("RPL",A1)+LEN("RPL")),SEARCH("M",A1,(SEARCH("RPL",A1)+LEN("RPL")))-(SEARCH("RPL",A1)+LEN("RPL"))))
```

This is basically:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,X,SEARCH("M",A1,X)-Y))
```

Where X is the start location:

```
=SEARCH("RPL",A1)+LEN("RPL")
```

And Y is the end location:

```
=SEARCH("M",A1,X)
```